# An "Expecting property name:" error started coming - OAuth 2.0 Google APIs Client Library for Python

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I took this example from [google code samples.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#retrieve_my_uploads) It was working earlier, but suddenly it stopped working. I tried reseting everything. Still not luck.

What is that I'm doing wrong?

Here is the error log.

```
Kshitij:oauth Kshitij$ python playlistitems.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playlistitems.py", line 51, in <module>
    scope=YOUTUBE_READONLY_SCOPE)
  File "/Users/Kshitij/django project/trailers_backend/oauth/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Kshitij/django project/trailers_backend/oauth/oauth2client/client.py", line 1343, in flow_from_clientsecrets
    client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(filename, cache=cache)
  File "/Users/Kshitij/django project/trailers_backend/oauth/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 145, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "/Users/Kshitij/django project/trailers_backend/oauth/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 103, in _loadfile
    obj = simplejson.load(fp)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load **kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
  ValueError: Expecting property name: line 16 column 3 (char 561)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had added extra parameters in the `client_secrets.json` which is why `flow_from_clientsecrets()` wasn't able to parse it. It started working after I removed them.